# Interaction is null

Tags: experience-analytics, experience-profile, contact-facets

When a user submits's a form on the contact us page, I am creating a contact in xDB as:

```csharp
try
{
    //Identify the user
    Tracker.Current.Session.Identify(model.Email);

    //Get the contact
    var contact = Tracker.Current.Session.Contact;

    if (contact != null)
    {
        //Update contact
        SitecoreContactManager.UpdateXdbContact(model.Email, model.FirstName, model.LastName, model.Phone);
    }
    else
    {
        //Create contact
        Tracker.Current.Session.Contact = SitecoreContactManager.GetXdbContact(model.Email);
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error($"error in creating or updating contact for identifier {model.Email}", exception, this);
}
```

this works well locally and on DEV but in live, it is throwing an error as :

> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException Message: this.Interaction
> should not be null Source: Sitecore.Analytics at
> Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.StandardSession.Identify(String userName)
> at
> uk.co.biggroup.www.api.ContactFormController.CreateUpdateContactInXdb(FormDetailsModel
> model)

- I have checked the connections to mongo databases(I can see data in there)
- I have rebuild reporting database.
- compared the Sitecore `/admin/showconfig.aspx` of DEV and LIVE, I could not able to see anything obvious.

Sitecore version: 8.2 rev. 170614 (Update-4)

Did anyone experience this issue before?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68331/discussion-on-question-by-dheeraj-palagiri-interaction-is-null).

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: No, i have raised a support ticket with sitecore

Comment: Did you heard anything from Sitecore on this?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. did you hear back anything from Sitecore with that support ticket?

Answer (score 1):

It mostly seems related to `Null Session`. If you have multiple CD servers, you should have `shared session`. Since you are using MongoDb, here is an article from Sitecore to configure Shared session with MongoDb provider. I would suggest to make changes on Live according to this and then check. It is not needed locally as we don't have multiple CDs there.

[Shared session with MongoDb provider](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/walkthrough--configuring-a-shared-session-state-database-using-the-mongodb-provider.html)

- You need a shared session database.
- Then configure it on CD server to use it.
- Also, if you are creating any custom object to store in session, do create is as `serializable`.